# MySQL 5.5 to RDS 5.6 Replication Error

Tags: mysql, replication, amazon-rds

I am facing following error and unable to fix it. So far I have disabled binlog checksum on the `RDS`.

```
[Warning] Slave I/O: Notifying master by SET @master_binlog_checksum= @@global.binlog_checksum failed with error: Unknown system variable 'binlog_checksum', Error_code: 1193
2015-06-29 11:01:01 8026 [Warning] Slave I/O: Unknown system variable 'SERVER_UUID' on master. A probable cause is that the variable is not supported on the master (version: 5.5.41-0ubuntu0.12.04.1-log), even though it is on the slave (version: 5.6.22-log), Error_code: 1193
```

Answer (score 5):

This is due to MySQL Master and Slave version mismatch

The message below is clear, and confirms the master/slaves run different versions. The variable `SERVER_UUID` is not supported with `MySQL 5.5` but is supported with `MySQL 5.6`

```
2015-06-29 11:01:01 8026 [Warning] Slave I/O: Unknown system variable 'SERVER_UUID' on master. A probable cause is that the variable is not supported on the master (version: 5.5.41-0ubuntu0.12.04.1-log), even though it is on the slave (version: 5.6.22-log), Error_code: 1193
```

Please have a look at **[Link1](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=70829) & [Link2](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=68164)**

Comment: So what to do now, can I not just enable replication somehow.. can you help thanks